# Нулевое окончание

Tags: морфология, окончания

Скажите, пожалуйста, как давно существует понятие "нулевое окончание"?
Оказывается, ошибочно считать, что в слове "стол" нет окончания, оно там нулевое.
Кто и когда "нафантазировал" там нулевое окончание?
Вся наши дружная компания из 15 человек с высшим техническим образованием советских времен не может объяснить  нашему маленькому ученику такое чудо.

Comment: Окончание слова - это его *хвост*, Маргарита! Так смело и объясняйте. Когда слово "сидит" в именительном падеже, то хвост прячется под ...

Comment: По моему мнению, высказывание "Слово X (например, "стол") имеет нулевое окончание." равносильно высказыванию "Слово X (например, "стол") не имеет окончания.".

P.S. Аналогичный пример

Высказывание "На небе ни облака." равносильно высказыванию "На небе ноль облаков.".

Comment: Пример из математики: (1) Функция У в точке Х равна нулю (окончание слова "стол" в И.п. равно нулю).  (2)Функция Z на данном множестве из 6-и падежей не определена/не существует (окончания у слова "пальто"  нет).

Answer (score 13):

Детям, которые не видят разницы между "нет окончания" и "нулевое окончание" я объясняю так. Вызываю ученика. Поворачиваю его лицом к классу и спрашиваю: "У Пети есть нос?" - "Да!" Поворачиваю ученика затылком к классу. Задаю то же вопрос:"У Пети есть нос?" Кто-нибудь кричит "нет". "Как? У Пети нет носа? А куда же он делся? У Пети есть нос, но в этом положении его не видно... У Пети сейчас - нулевой нос" . Так и у слов. Стол-стола-столу-столом-о столе - это одно слово в разных падежах,в слове "стол" есть окончание, его слышно во всех падежах, кроме именительного и винительного. В именительном и винительном - нулевое окончание.

Окончание- это изменяемая часть слова, поэтому если слово не изменяется, то ...(продолжают дети всегда сами) - у него нет окончания. Пальто, сейчас, вверх - и т.п.  У изменяемых слов есть окончание, оно может быть выражено материально, а может быть нулевым.

Comment: Забавный наглядный пример))) +1

Comment: Кто и когда придумал нулевое окончание? Словах столе, столу и т.  д. окончания есть, а в слове стол его нет. Все остальное просто  несуразица, забивающая голову детям.  Остается вопрос: "Кто и когда придумал , что в сове стол есть окончание?

Comment: "Ты видишь в слове стол окончание?" - "Нет!" - "Я тоже. А оно есть!"  
Филология все-таки считается наукой (типа метеорологии), поэтому в ней есть своя доля условно-понятных терминов, с чем приходится мириться. Про дуплексив слыхали? *Нашел в лесу кабана уже убитым в прошлом году, всего в двух шагах от турбазы*.   
Филологический прогноз на понедельник : "Днем ожидаются слабые примыкания притяжательных местоимений к отглагольным существительным среднего рода, плавно переходящие в согласованное управление. Вечером частичная междомуть и качественные прилагательные с краткими причастиями. ..."

Comment: ***Маргарита255***, я как мог объяснил суть в своем ответе. А что касается "кто и когда" - это вопрос не слишком актуальный. Думаю, что о нем знали еще древние греки и латиняне.  
  
>Пальто, сейчас, вверх - и т.п.     
  
Даже если отбросить наречия, почему не сформулировать так, что "пальто" имеет нулевые окончания во всех падежах? По мне так куда логичнее - и общность не теряется.  
Кстати, мне видится тут некая связь с вопросом о типе грамматической связи с притяжательными местоимениями третьего лица.  Кстати, я там тоже этим пальто оперировал.   
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/26361/

Answer (score 10):

Если объяснять математически, то есть число 100. В этом числе одна сотня и по ноль десятков и единиц. То, что десятков и единиц ноль, не означает, что их нет вообще и 100 не является суммой этих десятков и единиц. Если из 100 вычесть 1, будет 99.

В существительном *раз-дел-0* у нас одна приставка, один корень и ноль окончаний, но назвать его отсутствующим нельзя, так как в других падежах оно проявляется (*раздела, разделу, разделом* и пр.). А вот в слове *пальто* окончания нет вообще, так как оно нигде не проявляется.

Что касается когда и кем, точно сказать не могу, но ориентировочно должно было появится в 20-х годах ХХ века, так как в 1918 была реформа грамматики, убравшей обязательное окончание у слова. В царской России писалось *раз-дѣ́л-ъ*. После реформы, в тех словах где было окончание **-ъ**, оно стало нулевым.

Нулевым может быть даже корень, правда это только одно слово **вы-0-ну-л**, где выделяются следующие морфемы: приставка вы-, суффиксы -ну- и -л- (последний указывает на прошедшее время).

Comment: Насчет нулевого корня в "вынуть" - это упрощенное и весьма спорное утверждение.  
Там просто часть корня срослась с приставкой, вторая - с суффиксом.
Т.е. один звук одновременно принадлежит разным частям слова (а здесь таки хитрых звуков - два). Ну или по другой версии - граница междк корнем и аффиксами проходит внутри звука.  
Подобное встречается и в других словах, подвергшихся историческому переразложению, осложненному  фонетическими процессами, но там этот факт малозначим и обычно это не оговаривается.

Answer (score 7):

Это был РИТОРИЧЕСКИЙ вопрос? Если нет, то придумал его, вернее, открыл  Иван Александрович Бодуэн де Куртенэ ещё в 1881 году, затем его поддержал Ф. Ф. Фортунатов и другие учёные.

Что говорить ребёнку, Вам подсказали, кстати, дети это обычно понимают, взрослым труднее объяснить.Я тоже училась в советской школе, но нам это говорили, и мы знали о нулевом окончании, просто Вы забыли.

О том, что оно есть и нельзя говорить , что в сущ.СТОЛ, ХЛЕБ,БРАТ нет окончания,говорит история языка.
В древненовгородском диалекте (в берестяных грамотах)в им. пад. ед. ч. муж. р. твердого склонения окончанием было -е. Это окончание встречается у существительных брате ‘брат?, прилагательных меретве ‘мертв?, местоимений саме ‘сам?, причастий погублене ‘погублен?, в именной части перфекта — забыле ‘забыл?. Во всем остальном славянском мире -е соответствует в древнюю эпоху окончание -ъ (например, братъ, самъ), а после падения редуцированных ъ и ь — нулевая флексия (брат, сам).( буквами ъ «ер» и ь «ерь» в древности обозначались особые сверхкраткие звуки, несколько похожие в своем произношении соответственно на [ы] и [и], которые окончательно исчезли из русского языка в начале XIII века). Сама буква Ъ в произношении уже приближалась к нулю, потому её и убрали, оставили только как разделительный твёрдый знак. Букву убрали, а значение её осталось. Это окончание говорит о том, что это сущ. муж.рода,ед.ч..им. пад. А если бы здесь не было окончания совсем, то ничто не могло бы сказать о роде, числе и падеже, слово было бы неизменяемым, как, например, жюри ( как узнать о роде?)

Как принято говорить в науке, нулевое окончание представляет собой значимое отсутствие. Понятие "нуля" для анализа языка очень важно: это "отсутствие", противопоставляемое "наличию": нулевой-положительный.Вы же не возмущаетесь наличием термина "Нулевая связка" ЕСТЬ ("Я ученик" вместо "я есть ученик") в составном именном сказуемом?  Нулевое окончание в склонении современных славянских языков - широко известное явление.В русском языке нулевые окончания есть в следующих формах слов:
1) у сущ.им.пад., ед.ч., муж.рода  и жен. рода 3-го скл.: стол, дочь;

2) у части сущ. род. пад., множ. числа: нет сил ,нет солдат,армий;

3) у кратких прилагательных в форме единственного числа, мужского рода: весел , счастлив;

4) у притяжательных прилагательных с суффиксом -ий: лисий , волчий ;

5) у глаголов в форме прошедшего времени, единственного числа, мужского рода: читал, пел .

И хорошо, что это вводят в младших классах, дальше будет труднее, а разве легко понять в начальной школе , что я = 2 звука - й+а(яма)? Но ведь понимают, а некоторые старшеклассники не понимают, потому что не хотят понять.

Comment: >Но ведь понимают, а некоторые старшеклассники не понимают, потому что не хотят понять.  
  
Потому, что их читать учили раньше чем слушать. )))  

Если по сути. Я не очень понимаю, при чем тут Иван Александрович и история языка вообще. Ну да Бог с ними. Я уже не первый раз пытаюсь  задать (в разных формулировках) вопрос об окончаниях неизменяемых слов. Конкретно. Почему про пальто верно говорить, что у него нет окончаний, а не то, что у него во всех падежах одинаковое нулевое окончание? По моим представлениям, второе - куда более логично.

Comment: Потому что окончание (или лучше отражает смысл термин ФЛЕКСИЯ (от лат. flexio - сгибание) - это часть слова, выражающая грамматические значения при словоизменении (склонении, спряжении)и служащая для связи слов в предложении, а слово ПАЛЬТО не склоняется, не изменяется , следовательно, нет такой части в слове, чтобы она указала на число и падеж, слава богу, есть -О, совпадающее с окончанием среднего рода,(а вот у жюри и кенгуру и того нет)и нет части слова, которая бы повлияла на сочетание  его с другими словами: надел пальто, говорил о пальто, восхищался пальто.

Comment: Нуль - когда в других формах появляется положительное значение.Нуля нет, а вот -О похоже на окончание, но если его выделить как окончание, то это будет окончание им. падежа как точка отсчёта,начало словоизменения - снова противоречит неизменяемости. Тогда уж было бы "о пальте".

Comment: Людмила, спасибо, конечно, но это же проповедь, а не ответ на конкретный вопрос... Вы не обозначили критерий, по которому **правильно** (логично, целесообразно) а) разделять понятия нет окончания и нулевое окончание и б) относить конкретное слово одному из вариантов.  
  
Моя-то мысль проста как валенок. Пальто не склоняется, но существительные слоняются. Значит у всех т.н. "несклоняемых существительных" падежные окончания нулевые.  
А Ваш довод насчет смысла слова "флексия" одинаково применим и к случаям, "нулевой флексии". В слове "стол" ***нет*** части, которая указывает на его падеж.

Comment: Неверно, не в слове нет части, а в форме слова,она проявляется в другой форме этого же слова - в форме родительного пад. или мн.ч. - стол/ы - стол/а, а у ПАЛЬТО и в родительном пальто, нет формы, где бы она проявилась. Нулевое окончание слово СТОЛ выражает грамматическое значение рода, числа, падежа.Мы так и говорим: нулевое окончание свидетельствует о муж. р.,ед.ч., им.или вин.пад. в противоположность неизменяемому ПАЛЬТО, где о роде говорит О, а о числе и падеже не говорит ничто.

Comment: Критерий тоже понятен: проявляется окончание в другой форме - нулевое, не проявляется-его в слове нет.

Comment: >не в слове нет части, а в форме слова  
  
По такой логике получается, что у слова "пальто" вообще нет словоформы. Ибо она "не проявляется".

Остальное, простите, не аргументы, а вдалбливание нерадивому ученику того, что он не знает. )))  
Вы бы мне просто сказали, что такое построение грамматики (разделение понятий "нет окончания" и "нулевое окончание" не по признаку принадлежности к частям речи, а свойствам конкретного слова) объясняется историческими причинами.

Comment: (+)
Или в ней есть логика, которая проявляется в дальнейшем там-то и там-то. При рассмотрении типов грамматической связи, например. 

Ладно, спасибо, на этом лучше прерваться.

Comment: У слова "пальто" есть одна словоформа. Потому и одна, что окончания нет.

Answer (score 3):

Я не знаю как объяснить ребенку, ибо у меня подобных проблем не возникало.
Ни у самого, ни с ребенком.

Но компании из 15-ти человек с верхним техническим объясняю легко.

Если на улице нулевая температура, то это не значит, что её нету вообще. 
А если у вас "нет температуры", то она далеко не нулевая.

Сдается мне, что нет окончание и нулевое окончание в школьном контексте полные синонимы и нет оснований бороться против одного в силу другого.
наоборот. Если у Пети нет яблок, значит у него их ноль, разве нет? Если у слова нет окончания, то в нём (в окончании) - ноль звуков, нет? Или дети в школе в век компьютеров не знают, что такое "ноль"?

Признаться, идея с носом мне не совсем нравится. Нос-то есть. И он отнюдь не "нулевой". Просто не виден. Это совсем другое. В свое время (класса с пятого, ибо в третьем и четвертом в школе не учился) из-за подобных нестыковок и недомолвок частенько думал, что мне просто целенаправленно морочат голову. )))
Это я в основном не про русский язык, но и с русским случалось недоразумения. Но не смею настаивать.

Элен, отвечаю здесь
//----------------------

> > > > > > Вопрос в том, кому и зачем это надо. Может, вы объясните, чем руководствовался автор этой идеи?
>
> Автор этой идеи руководствовался заботой о школьниках.

Простите, но я не спрашивал о школьниках. Вы не поняли. (Или "в толк не взяли").

> Они (ученики) быстрее понимают то, что Вы никак в толк не возьмёте.

Я не могу взять в толк, ***зачем нужна такая система определений***. А школьники понимают, ***зачем она нужна***? Не смешите. Они (так же как и я, кстати, Вы на меня напраслину наговариваете) понимают, ***что*** им говорят - но ***зачем*** это не понимают ни они, ни я, ни Вы. Если назовете эту цель (аргументировано), то я сразу пойму.  Да что-то не получается ни у Вас, ни у Ваших предшественников. Только не надо повторять что "они лучше понимают". Назовите хотя бы что именно они "понимают".

Если опять не поняли. ЖИ и ШИ пишут с И совсем не потому, что они так "лучше понимают". А потому, что так правильно, объяняется традицией и исторической фонетикой. 
Вот и аргументируйте, если не трудно, идея "у слова стол флексия нулевая, а у пальто - её нет" правильно, а не просто волюнтаристски задано.

> А вот чем руководствуются люди, изобретающие вопросы ЕГЭ, мне непонятно. (Я о вопросе про грамматическую связь в словосочетании "его появление".)

При чем тут ЕГЭ? Но если это вопрос, то они руководствовались не иначе как  соображениями типа "они так лучше понимают".

Но вопрос-то на самом деле в другом. А как правильно (логичнее, понятнее - на Ваш выбор), считать, что несклоняемые имена/местоимения не имеют флексий вообще - и, как следствие, путаться во всех формулировках, это понятие использующих ("его пальто" - это просто один из примеров) или сделать формулировку универсальной - и снимающей многие нестыковки во всей системе определений.

Вот где собака-то порылась.
А Вы мне - про детский сад и "лучше понимают". А как они "понимают хуже", позвольте спросить? Если есть "лучше", значит и "хуже" должно быть, нет?

Answer (score 2):

Окончание - это часть слова, которая служит для выражения грамматических значений. Любая форма склоняемого существительного обязана иметь окончание. Окончания существительных выражают грамматические значения числа и падежа, нулевое окончание слова "стол" выражает значения ед.числа, И.п. Соответственно,  нельзя сказать, что окончания нет.

ОТВЕТ 2. Нельзя сказать, что слова стол и пальто "одинаковые". У стола нулевое окончание выражает грамматические значения числа и падежа, а у пальто грамматические значения определяются только в сочетаниях с другими словами: новое пальто, зимние пальто, в зимнем пальто. Связь согласование "существительное-прилагательное строится на согласовании трех грамматических значений, и дети должны это понимать.

ПОПУТНОЕ ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ
Мне кажется, что при изучении русского языка мы недооцениваем способности наших школьников. Посмотрите, какой уровень других изучаемых в школе наук - физики, химии, математики! И они все понимают и разбираются не хуже учителей. А мы с ними, как с малыми детьми: вот птичечка полетела, а вот домик стоит. Скажи: до-мик, и т.д.

ОТВЕТ 3. Правил всего два:для склоняемых и несклоняемых существительных. Кроме того, я думаю, что  правила вообще никто не придумывает. Просто есть проблема (несклоняемые существительные) - и есть решение (особый подход к грамматике этих слов).

А дети, конечно, разные. Не научишь того, кто не хочет учиться. Поэтому уровень обучения должен быть разным: базовые знания для всех и особый курс для гуманитарных классов. А то не видать нам будущих Фортунатовых (смайлик).

Comment: Дети разные. Есть, кому это интересно и кто понимает, а есть те, которым "до-мик" будешь диктовать до самого выпуска. Беда, если они вдруг в одном классе оказываются: кого-нибудь, да упускаешь.

Comment: >ОТВЕТ 2. Нельзя сказать, что слова стол и пальто "одинаковые".  
  
И не надо говорить. Все слова разные. Но это не значит, что для каждого слова надо придумывать отдельное правило.   

ЗЫ Я не про детей. Со взрослыми бы разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

В школе нулевое окончание "ввели" на рубеже 60-70-х годов. Когда я училась, в стове "стол" не было окончания. О нулевом окончании впервые услышала в институте. Дети обычно легко это понимают, как и про нулевые суффиксы.

Comment: Я закончил школы, если 74-м, про нулевые окончания ничего со школы не помню. Во всяком случае, ни о каком противопоставлении "нулевого окончания" его полному отсутствию речи не было. Кстати, это был тот когда, когда в 10-м ввели самостоятельный русский язык.     

Но вопрос не в этом. Вы тоже полагаете, что в школе "нулевое окончание" и "нет окончания" - это разные понятия? И это логично и правильно?

Comment: Я окончила школу в 1971, не помню, откуда узнала о нулевом суффиксе, а что знала это на 1 курсе института - помню. Но что мы не говорили, что нет окончания - это точно, может, просто при выделении окончания не ставили пустой квадратик, не обозначали. Прекрасно помню, как нам объясняли, в каких частях речи нет окончания и почему: нет, потому что слово неизменяемое, а окончание - изменяемая часть слова. В подробности никто не вдавался, и мысли не было.

Comment: Я окончила школу в 80. Нулевое окончание тогда уже в школьном курсе было.   behemothus, поверьте, в школе "нет окончания" и "нулевое окончание" - это разные понятия. В ЕГЭ не так давно было задание А 13 (по морфемике). Могли спросить, например, в каком слове 2 морфемы. И вариант "стол" был бы правильным ответом.

Comment: >behemothus, поверьте, в школе "нет окончания" и "нулевое окончание" - это разные понятия.

Вопрос в том, кому и зачем это надо. Может, вы объясните, чем руководствовался автор этой идеи?   
  
>Могли спросить, например, в каком слове 2 морфемы.  
  
А что это доказывает? Да, я понимаю, что нулевая морфема - тоже морфема. Не понимаю, почему (при таком подходе) в слове "пальто" - одна.

Ну и то, зачем различать эти случаи в школе...

Comment: Это ответ на Ваш вопрос: "Вы тоже полагаете, что в школе "нулевое окончание" и "нет окончания" - это разные понятия?". А искать ответ на вопрос зачем? - дело неблагодарное, так можно все из программы повыбрасывать. Грамматика, как и математика, развивает логическое мышление. В случае с нулевым окончанием все логично.

Comment: Я не ставил так вопрос. Т.е. вопрос не о том, как преподают в школе, а о том, как объясняют разницу - и реальна ли эта разница в рамках школьной программы. Речь, подчеркиваю, только о существительных.

    А искать ответ на вопрос зачем? дело неблагодарное,

Если надо "искать", то, конечно, неблагодарное. Это значит, что реально его нет. Я не верю, что те, кто отстаивают правильность подхода, не знают, где им можно воспользоваться. Ну не ради же того, чтобы детям голову заморочить, придумано.

Comment: В русском слове пальто - две морфемы)  
Корень **пальт** и финаль **о**. Другие формы слова пальто с корнем ПАЛЬТ :  
пальт/ец/о  
пальт/ушк/а  
пальт/ишк/о  
пальт/ишечк/о  
пальт/ин/а  
пальт/ов/ый  
пальт/ированн/ый  
бес/пальт/ошн/ый...

Comment: Кстати.

>В случае с нулевым окончанием все логично.  
  
Вот именно в этой логичности я и хотел бы убедиться. 
А меня всеми силами убеждают в обратном. 

Кстати насчет математики. В математике разделяют понятия "нулевая вероятность события" и "событие невозможное". За ним стоит принципиальная разница. Вероятность того, что при бросании игральной кости она встанет на ребро - нулевая. А вот что, что выпадет семерка - событие невозможное (нет такой грани). Вот это логично.

Comment: >Вопрос в том, кому и зачем это надо. Может, вы объясните, чем руководствовался автор этой идеи?
Автор этой идеи руководствовался заботой о школьниках. Они (ученики) быстрее понимают то, что Вы никак в толк не возьмёте. 
А вот чем руководствуются люди, изобретающие вопросы ЕГЭ, мне непонятно. (Я о вопросе про грамматическую связь в словосочетании "его появление".)

Comment: Вопрос о "его появлении" - чистая провокация. Учителя должны бить тревогу, пока не поздно.

Answer (score 1):

Наличие окончания у слова – это свойство слова, флективность. Если окончания в одной из словоформ "не слышно", это не отменяет того, что оно есть.

У слова "стол" есть это окончание, которое проявляется в других словоформах. Если сказать, что у слова "стол" окончания нет вообще, это значит, что свойства у словоформ разные. Это нелогично.

Comment: Т.е. то, что свойства словоформы "пальто" отличается от свойств словоформы "шапка" - это нормально. А вот то что сама словоформа "стол" не лезет в общее прокрустово ложе  - это нелогично?

Comment: У СЛОВА "пальто" нет окончания. У этого СЛОВА отсутствует свойство "флективность". СЛОВА "шапка" и "стол" сим свойством обладают, то есть окончание у этих СЛОВ есть. То, что окончания нет у конкретных СЛОВОФОРМ, свойство СЛОВА не отменяет.

Comment: Не надо так кричать, я хорошо вижу.   
  
Вы как истинный грумантоид продолжаете переть на комод.
Я не знаю, при чем тут флективность, как и то, знаете ли об этом Вы.
Если Вы доказательно объясните, почему именно флективность (а не еще какая фиктивноность) определяет поход, то можете считать, что меня вы убедили. Иначе - хоть десять раз повторяйте - толку не много.

Comment: Людмила вам все прекрасно объяснила. Я тоже объяснил. Перечитайте. Еще раз. Еще. Если все равно не поймете, то у меня для вас плохие новости.

Comment: >то у меня для вас плохие новости.  
  
Вы признаетесь, что Вы - мульт Груманта?
Это давно уже не новость.))))

Пересвет, или кто Вы там. Давайте на паритете?!
Вы пречитываете все, что что я написал - и переспрашиваете, что не поняли прежде чем лезть со своми объяснениями. Идет?

Начните вот с этого:
"Не надо так кричать, я хорошо вижу".

Comment: Бегемотус, а в чем Вы-то видите проблему?! 
Я где-то чувствую, что Вы прекрасно понимаете то, что Вам говорят. 
Значит с чем-то несогласны?!

Comment: Ась? Я сто раз уже писал. Последний раз - Ларf.
Да, я прекрасно понимаю, что говорит Людмила. Это она меня не понимает.
Проблемы как такой нету. Разделять существительные на те, у которых есть нулевое окончание, и те, у которых нету, вполне возможно - и тут нет противоречия. Предлагаемый принцип тоже понятен.  
Под сомнение только одно. Что это удачный выбор системы определений.

Comment: (+)
Грамматики создаются людьми, так что о предопределенности речи не идет. Плюсов у него нет никаких (никто и не попытался из назвать), а минусы очевидны. Первый. "надеть пальто" - какой тип связи? Если у "пальто" нет флексии, то примыкание. Что противоречит естеству, ибо ясно, что пальто стоит в винительном падеже.  

Мне уже достаточно, чтобы поставить вопрос ребром: "Зачем использовать такую грамматику". Повторяю, мне достаточно хотя бы одного вразумительного примера того, что у принятой системы есть хоть какое-то применение, делающее её удобнее (удачнее, правильнее) прочих возможных.

Comment: (++)
В первую очередь - удачнее и удобнее той, о которой я говорил. ***Все*** неизменяемые существительные имеют нулевую падежную флексию. Это позволило бы непротиворечиво утверждать, что пальто в указанном сочетании стоит в винительном падеже. 
Вы же сами где-то об этом писали? "Надеть *зимнее* пальто" - вот же он, винительный.  
Или я не так Вас тогда понял?!
Или это не Вы были?!

Comment: В  слове  "стол"  окончания  нет (  или  есть,  но  нулевое ),  и  в  каком  падеже  это  слово  мы  узнаём  из  контекста.  В  слове  "пальто"  окончания  нет  (  или  оно  нулевое  во  всех  падежах  ),  и,  чтобы  определить  падеж  нам  опять  придётся  обратиться  к  контексту.  Какая  разница  для  обычного  школьника,  а  не  для  будущего  языковеда,  как  определять  это  наличие  отсутствия ?  Чем  "есть  ничего"  лучше  "ничего  нет" ?

Answer (score 0):

Я согласна с @behemothusом и @Галактионом.
Слово "нулевой" происходит от существительного нуль (ноль), от итал. *nulla* «ничто», от лат. *nullus* «никакой, ни один; несуществующий; пустой».
Объяснение нулевого окончания я считаю элементарным для понимания. Речь не об этом. Речь о том, что нулевой означает несуществующий, то есть вы даже не замечаете, что вы произносите.
Представьте, что вы говорите это на другом языке. Например, учите англичанина русскому языку. И говорите: "The word СТОЛ has a zero ending, and the word ПАЛЬТО doesn't have an ending". Ну и какая разница в данном утверждении?  Это одно и тоже.
Все это болтология. Высасывание из пальца. Усложнение. Все, что надо знать, так это то, что первое слово изменяется, а второе нет. И уметь ставить слово в правильную форму.